# swiftui blendMode is not match to sketch combine mode of difference

Tags: ios, layout, swiftui, sketchapp

I want to show text combine with Rectangle as below image. I have already draw it in sketch by Combined Shape of Difference mode. [image]

I code it in Xcode by SwiftUI, the code show as below:

```
struct DiffView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Text("DIFF")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .blendMode(.difference)
                .offset(x: 20, y: 0)
                
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

But the result is not as expected as in Sketch, the overlapping part on the left becomes black (expected to be white), and the letter on the right becomes yellow (expected to be blue).

[image]

How should I use swiftui blendMode correctly?`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

It takes into account background, so diff blue from white gives orange. So at first let's remove background from blending by using `compositingGroup`

```
struct DiffView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
                Color.blue
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Text("DIFF")
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(x: 20, y: 0)
                .blendMode(.difference)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

which gives

[image: demo1]

Well it is because pure difference does not have anything in background and thus gives `black` color. So your effect can be achieved by the following

```
struct DiffView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
                Color.orange
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Text("DIFF")
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(x: 20, y: 0)
                .blendMode(.difference)
        }
        .compositingGroup()
        .colorInvert()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

[image: demo2]