# SwiftUI: Blendmode with Text view making overlapping area white and rest as black

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a text view that switch colors to white for the region that's overlapping with another view and rest of it in black.

Below is the code tryout following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532197/swiftui-blendmode-is-not-match-to-sketch-combine-mode-of-difference) which uses blend mode but it makes the overlapped region green and it's based on the background view color.
**I want it as always white irrespective of the overlapping view color and rest of the text view in black**.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Color.purple.frame(width: 200, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 20)

            Text("Over")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(x: 10, y: 0)
                .blendMode(.difference)

        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot of the current result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 Texts and a mask instead.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.purple
                .frame(width: 200, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 20)

            Text("Over")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(x: 10, y: 0)

            Text("Over")
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .offset(x: 10, y: 0)
                .mask(Rectangle().frame(height: 20).offset(x: 0, y: 10))

        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

## Result:

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: Thanks @Tamás Sengel for taking your time to answer this question.One more thing is there any way around without duplication of views.

Comment: AFAIK there is no blend mode that achieves this